# Grafana use data with same timestamp

Tags: influxdb, grafana

We are looking into using Grafana to use as a dashboard to display some graphs and whatnot. But apparently all data in Grafana is with a timestamp and our data runs at night and we give it all the same timestamp.

In our mysql db it's like this:

```
2015-11-04 2015-11-05 xxx yyyy zzz
2015-11-04 2015-11-05 aaa bbb ccc
...
```

So can we use grafana for this? We don't need to be able to see the difference during the day, just total numbers. We don't want to overwrite our records however with eachother.

Thanks.

Comment: Grafana is used to display time series data. I understand you will have a different timestamp every night, right? Why can't you use that, then display the values for each day?

Comment: I could try that, indeed :) Thx.

Comment: Did you manage? You should group by 1 day, than it will show you the data per day.